# Can I estimate the mean of a dataset if I have its standard deviation and a portion of the full data that is higher than some threshold?

Tags: estimation, quantiles, order-statistics, truncation

I have a partial set of measurement data that is limited due to my tool's sensitivity. I know that the data is approximately normally distributed and I have a standard deviation from another data set that was within my measurement tool's range.

Is it possible to use this limited data to estimate its mean? In one case I have the upper 59% of the data and in another case I have the top 11%.

Comment: Yes you can, by expressing the joint distribution of what is observed, namely the upper 59% of a normally distributed sample.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Do you mean to take a scatter plot with the upper 59% on one axis and the full normal distribution on the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an iid sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, with density $f_\theta$, the sub-vector of [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) $V=(X_{(\alpha n)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ [where $0<\alpha<1$ and $\alpha n\in\mathbb N^*$] has density
$$\frac{n!}{(\alpha n-1)!}F_\theta(x_{(\alpha n)})^{\alpha n-1}\prod_{i=\alpha n}^n f_\theta(x_{(i)})\ \mathbb I_{x_{(\alpha n)}\le\cdots\le x_{(n)}}$$
This turns into the likelihood when seen as a function of $\theta$, hence it can be on principle maximised in $\theta$.

Furthermore, since this is a missing data model, the [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) can be implemented here. More precisely, this means considering the missing part of the sample, $W=(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(\alpha n-1)})$, in the complete log-likelihood
$$-n \log\sigma-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_{(i)}-\mu)^2\\=-n \log\sigma-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha n-1} (X_{(i)}-\mu)^2\\\qquad-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum^{n}_{i=\alpha n} (X_{(i)}-\mu)^2$$
and taking its expectation
$$\mathbb E_{\mu_0,\sigma_0}\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha n-1} (X_{(i)}-\mu)^2\Big|V\right]$$
even though the first two moments of a Normal order statistic are not available in [closed form](https://doi.org/10.2307/2333139). However, the update in the M-step of the EM algorithm only involves
$$\mu_{t+1}=\mathbb E_{\mu_t,\sigma}\left[\overline{X_{1:n}}\big|X_{(\alpha n)},\ldots, X_{(n)}\right]$$
which can be expressed as
$$\frac{\alpha n-1}{n} \left\{\mu_t-\sigma f_{\mu_t,\sigma}(x_{(\alpha n)})\big/F_{\mu_t,\sigma}\right\}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=\alpha n}^n X_{(i)}$$
with some intermediate steps$^1$, including the derivation of a [truncated Normal mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/404582/7224). In conclusion, **the EM algorithm can be implemented without any Monte Carlo step**.

---

$^1$Another explanation for the result is that $W$ conditional on $V$ is (i) conditional on $X_{(\alpha n)}$ only and (ii) distributed from the original distribution truncated at $X_{(\alpha n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple using the method of moments.

Suppose $X$ is normally distributed, $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$. And suppose $Y$ is the highest $59\%$ of $X$. Then linear transformations of the numerical calculations for $N(0,1)$ give:
\begin{align}
E[Y]&=\mu + 0.948\sigma\\
E[Y^2]&=\mu^2 + 2(0.948)\mu\sigma + 1.216\sigma^2
\end{align}

In more generality, let $Y$ be the highest $r$ of $X$, where $0<r<1$. Let $Q_r$ be the quantile of the normal distribution for $1-r$, so $Q_{0.59}=-0.228$ and $Q_{0.11}=1.227$. Then
\begin{align}
E[Y]&=\mu + K_r\sigma\\
E[Y^2]&=\mu^2 + 2K_r \mu \sigma + \sigma^2(1 - K_r Q_r)\\
\text{where }K_r&=\frac{e^{-Q_r^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1-r)}
\end{align}

So $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$ can be estimated from the sample, and then $\mu$ and $\sigma$ can be determined by solving the two equations. Or, if a value for $\sigma$ is taken from another source, $\mu$ can be estimated from the first equation alone.